# Recommended face detection tools/SDK/etc

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I'm looking for a quick way to detect faces in pictures (stored as JPG or any other popular image format). Code in any popular programming language will do (Python, C#, Java, Matlab, etc.). I'm also willing to implement an algorithm by myself, as long as it is proven to be a good working one.

Alternatively, if there are known freeware (preferably open, but not necessary) tools or SDKs for the problem, I'll try them too.

Finally, Commercial products would be considered as well, if all else fails, so recommend those too.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a open source library that has support for face recognition.

Answer (score 3):

Emgu.CV is a C# wrapper for OpenCV. There is a sample project that performs face recognition with adjsutable parameters just like in OpenCV.

Comment: Facial detection (per the original question) is supported - facial recognition is not directly supported.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these guys, I've used this once partially for a project.

http://ayonix.com/en/products/software/ayofa.html

Answer (score 1):

I wrote about resources and example code for face classification in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412387/face-recognition/10708503#10708503).

If you want a quick way to do face recognition look at the example code for face recognition in OpenCV for Python or C++ [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceRecognition).

There is also a Matlab code that I found very useful and is ready to run with a single click right [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17066-fld-based-face-recognition-system)